# How to prevent flutter from automatically downloading android emulator when 'flutter run' is executed

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-emulator, cross-platform, android-sdk-tools

I am just beginning to learn cross-platform with flutter, but I chose not to use android studio as it is very hardware demanding and I am using low-end PC. I am using VS Code editor and set up everything successfully including android SDK. But I decided to use my physical phone for rather than emulator for the reason mentioned above. I have set up everything for that as well. However, when i execute `flutter run`, during the execution, it reaches a stage where it begin to download android emulator, but I don't want it to do so. Is there a way I can prevent it from downloading the emulator. Please can anyone help me out on this.

I tried adding `flutter.emulatorEnabled=false` into `gradle.properties` file but it didn't work.